# Is there a way to permanently change value of an variable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a list containing some values. And while using the app users can edit those values. But those changes are temporary. When I run the app again, it reverts back to the old values and not the values that were edited previously.

> **So is there a way to keep those changes ?**

Comment: save those changes to some persistence storage (like sharedPref) and read that value the next time app is launched.

Comment: How do you get your values at first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a package like [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store the values of those variables on the device and when the user opens the app again, you can read them instead of initializing them to a fixed value.

Alternatively, if you have a backend with user data you can store it there and read it from there.